# trying to use ng-repeat to create ng-model bindings

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function:

```
var app = angular.module('Hubbub-FrontEnd', []);

app.controller('DataEntryCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.entryFields = [
       {pHolder:'ID goes here',ngmodel:"kid"},
       {pHolder:'Description goes here',ngmodel:"desc"},
       {pHolder:'Drop Dead Date goes here',ngmodel:"ddd"}
   ];
});
```

This is called in the following `html`.

```
<div ng-controller="DataEntryCtrl">
      <span ng-repeat="entryField in entryFields">
            <input type="text" ng-model="{{entryField.ngmodel}}" placeholder=
"{{entryField.pHolder}}">
   </span>
   <button>Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing two-way data binding with the ngModel directive you don't need double curly braces `{{}}`. The double curly braces tell angular to evaluate an expression and print output, notice how you have to use them to display the contents of the placeholder

Here's the working version

```
<span ng-repeat="entryField in entryFields">
        <input type="text" 
               ng-model="entryField.ngmodel" 
               placeholder="{{entryField.pHolder}}">
</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/A8PkC/1/

Comment: I am facing the same issue, but jm's answer doesn't work (to my understanding of the problem). It merely sets the input's text value to the value of the json ngmodel field. It's not creating a binding.

Comment: A ha...I read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/7Gz_xm_FtV4) in angularjs Google Groups, and found a way to get it to work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gregsandell/G24J5/1/)